# Can not register asp.net 4.0 on IIS server on Windows 10

Tags: .net, iis, windows-10, .net-4.5, iis-8

On Windows 10 x64, according to 
[link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNET-40-has-not-been-registered-on-the-Web-server-You-need-to-manually-configure-your-Web-server.aspx)

I wanted to register asp.net 4.0 on IIS server.
But below error occurs:

[image]

When I enter Program features it looks like below:

[image]

So what more I can select to install?

**Update**

[image]

**Update2**

The reason I want to register asp.net 4.0 on IIS server is that I get below message when try to create new MVC4 project in visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by .. disabled Default Web Site on IIS. Strange, but true. When enabled it start to work. When I disable it it back again.

Answer (score 0):

Expand World Wide Web under Internet Information Services.

Comment: @user3057544 ASP.NET 4.6 can run 4.0 apps, so that's it.

Comment: so why I still get message from the first picture when try to run "aspnet_regiis -i" ?

Comment: @user3057544 because when that's checked and installed as Windows component, you no longer need to run that extra command.